# How to refresh color of custom drawn cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, drawrect

I have custom UITableViewCell class which implements custom drawn design (as you can see, the cell has shadow effect.)
As you can see below I'm trying to paint 1st cell with white color, any other cell must be gray.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorRef whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
if (_rowNumber == 0)
    CGColorRef lightColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
else
    CGColorRef lightColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
CGColorRef darkColor = _darkColor.CGColor;
CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, _paperRect);
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 7.0, shadowColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, _coloredBoxRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context); 
}
```

The problem is: when I'm using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier the method "drawRect" invoked only 3 times (my cells have height 200), so the fourth cell has same color like the first one.

Is there any way to manage this problem?
Thanks

UPDATE
i've tried to invoke my custom redraw method from UITableViewController, but i have got "null" context error

```
- (void)refreshColorOfRow:(int)row{
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 if (row > 0)
     _lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:200.0f/255.0f green:199.0f/255.0f blue:200.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
 else
     _lightColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:240.0f/255.0f green:240.0f/255.0f blue:240.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0];
CGColorRef lightColor = _lightColor.CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);
CGContextFillRect(context, _coloredBoxRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath` you could call `[cell setNeedsDisplay];`.

But why don't you use `[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColorXY]];` if you only want some simple colors and shadows?

**EDIT:**
Like Guo Luchuan said, is an often called `drawRect:` a performance-killer. 
Just try it simple ;)

```
NSIndexPath *selectedCell; //Declare this in your .h

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
    }
    if (selectedCell.section==indexPath.section && selectedCell.row==indexPath.row) {
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"The Choosen One"];
    } else {
        [cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
        [cell.textLabel setText:@"FOO"];
    }
    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    selectedCell=indexPath;
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

And for the shadows you can play around with..

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CALayer *layer=[cell layer]; //Or [tableView layer] or whatever you need
[layer setShadowColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
[layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1, 1)];
[layer setShadowOpacity:1.0];
[layer setMasksToBounds:NO];
```

Comment: I don't use `[cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yourColorXY]];` because i'm kinda noob. I appreciate you help in advance ^)

Comment: @AndreyKaskaad -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath will be invoked many times , and the you must draw many times , your app will very very very unefficiency

Comment: I just added an Example to my answer

Comment: @xapslock i've just found out that your QuartzCore shadows are performance killers too. I test it on a real device... So be careful with it.

Comment: Yea, it's tricky if you don't use it carefully. But there are some performance Tricks... view.layer.shadowPath=[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;

Comment: @xapslock lol I just came up to post some info about the shadowPath. I've just tested it. Works perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're setting `_rowNumber` as a property for your `UITableViewCell` subclass. 
You should call setNeedsDisplay in the setter to force redrawing :

```
-(void) setRowNumber:(int)value {
    _rowNumber = value;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can make the `first cell` and `other cells` different `identifier` , such as `first cell`s resueIdentifier is `@"first"` ; `other cells`s resueIdentifier is `@"others"` and then in your custom cell , you can creat a `BOOL _isFirstCell` to mark `first cell` and then in the  `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect` method , you can draw both type cell use `if else` statment

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGColorRef whiteColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
if (_isFirstCell)
    CGColorRef lightColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
else
    CGColorRef lightColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
CGColorRef darkColor = _darkColor.CGColor;
CGColorRef shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.1 green:0.1 blue:0.1 alpha:0.5].CGColor;
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, whiteColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, _paperRect);
CGContextSaveGState(context);

CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 2), 7.0, shadowColor);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, lightColor);

CGContextFillRect(context, _coloredBoxRect);
CGContextRestoreGState(context); 
}
```